# Spring data JPA bulk search for List of different ID

Tags: database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table named Query_details which contains a list of queries posted by users. It also contains an order_id which is mapped to the payment_details table.

QUESTION:

I want to search and get all the order_ids for a particular id from the Query_details table and then I have to fetch the payment_details for all those individual order_ids. What is the bulk / efficient way to do this in spring data JPA? Is there a bulk way that exists in spring data JPA??